# React-Bootstrap accordion not working with map iteration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

i have implemented the accordion according to the react-bootstrap documentation. Everything working fine except when one panel is clicked to expand other expanded panel are not closing. It's working fine without map iterator but with map its not working. My codes are given below:

**Accordion.js**

```
return (
   <div className="accordion-container">
       <h1>Accordion Component</h1>
          {posts.map(post =>
             <Section post={post} key={post.id} item={post.id.toString()}/>
         )}
   </div>
);
```

**Section.js**

```
class Section extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      activeKey: "1"
    };
  }

  handleSelect(activeKey) {
    this.setState({ activeKey });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.item);
    return (
        <PanelGroup 
            accordion
            id="accordion-controlled-example"
            activeKey={this.state.activeKey}
            onSelect={this.handleSelect}
        >
            <Panel eventKey={this.props.item}>
                <Panel.Heading>
                    <Panel.Title toggle>{this.props.post.title}</Panel.Title>
                </Panel.Heading>
                <Panel.Body collapsible>
                    {this.props.post.body}
                </Panel.Body>
            </Panel>
        </PanelGroup>
    );
  }

}
```

Expert's help needed ..

Comment: Each `Section` consists of a `PanelGroup` with one `Panel` each. Shouldn't you wrap all Panels in just one `PanelGroup` for it to work?

Comment: Oh Savage.. what a silly mistake and hitting up my head from yesterday :( ... thanks a lot dear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `Section` consists of a `PanelGroup` with one `Panel` each in your code. If your instead use one single `PanelGroup` for all Panels, they will close automatically as expected.